# C# control.find explanation

Tags: c#, winforms, methods, find, controls

so i have been using the `control.find` for a while now, and it works like a charm.
I like to understand the things that i use.

`Control txt = this.Controls.Find(x + "_" + y + "_" + z, true)[0] as TextBox;`

`txt.Text = string.Empty;`

The above is an example of one of the ways i use this method,where x, y, z are of type `int` (or even `string` sometimes), it works REALLY well with my procedurally generated controls, since i have so many of them and some methods of mine require a specific text box to be accessed.

Now [MSDN - Control.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx), is mostly very straightforward with regards to this method, except for one thing, which brings me to my question.

`[0]` : this badboy, is where im trying to better my understanding of this method.

I'v always just left it as it is, since the method bombs out if its deleted. I would like to know at least 3 things, anything else would be a bonus, with regards to `[0]`, firstly, what is it, why is it there and what possible useful scenarios are there for this guy?

In closing, i have no problems using this method, i use it a lot for different types of controls, this is purely a fact finding question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ControlCollection.Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `Control[]`, so possibly multiple controls. The reason is that you could have multiple controls on the form with the same name.

Your second parameter is a `bool` which you have set to `true`. It indicates whether this control should be searched recursively or only in the parent control.

So your code is safe if you never have two controls with the same name.

Otherwise you should

1. avoid duplicate names
2. or, if it is desired, use a loop to iterate these controls instead of accesssing only the first

Note that you can't add controls with the same name via designer which detects duplicate names. But you are free to add controls with the same name programmatically.

Comment: all my controls have unique names, they are all generated in for loops with set boundaries; what i don't understand is how to effectively use [0]

Comment: @JuanPike: what means effectively? Accessing an item in an array via index is very effectove

Comment: yes, they are very effective, but i mean adding more controls to them and then accessing them from the array when i need it.

Comment: @JuanPike: it's still not clear. You get an array from the `Find` method. It normally contains only a single control which you access via index 0, so f.e. `mycontrols[0]`. If you have multiple with the same name and  you want to loop them you could use `foreach(Control c in mycontrols]{...}`. Arrays are fixed sized so you can't add items

Comment: i'v been experimenting with what you said and i understand it a lot more clearer now, thank you for your input (: - great help

Answer (score 2):

> what is it, why is it there

If you look at the return value: `Control[]` of the `Find` method, you see that it returns an array of all possible matches. with `[0]` you take the first element. You could also access the first element by using

```
this.Controls.Find(x + "_" + y + "_" + z, true).First() as TextBox;
```

EDIT: this version above is not really save. A safer version would check whether a match was really found:

```
Control[] asd = this.Controls.Find(x + "_" + y + "_" + z, true);

if(asd.Any())  // if you have found any elements 
{
    TextBox t = asd.First() as TextBox;
    t.Text = "Whatever";
}
```

If you want to get multiple Controls of the same type you could use the `OfType` method:

```
List<Button> asd = this.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList();
```

This will get you all `Button`s in your form.

Imaginge a case where you have 10 buttons and 4 of them have a special ending in the name(maybe for saving different formats) like:

> btn_save_txt
>   btn_save_dat
>   btn_save_xml
>   ...

If you want to search for all buttons with a similar name you could use this:

```
List<Button> asd = this.Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(x => x.Name.Contains("save")).ToList();
```

Now this would give you only the buttons that are for saving

Comment: does that mean i could load multiple controls into the array?

Comment: Yes, but with the Find method only if the controls have all the same name, as Tim Schmelter already explained. The key parameter searches only for exact matches.

Comment: @JuanPike I edited my answer and added a possibility to search for multiple controls and also with unspecific names. Have a look

Comment: MongZhu, you and @TimSchmelter have really improved my understanding on this topic, thank you both. both answers answer my question in different ways so unfortunately i cant pick just one.

Comment: @JuanPike you are welcome. I would also have gone for Tim's answer. Especially because it describes ways to make your code safe. I upvoted it also.